# How to start a process under current User?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I want to run a EXE file under current user in windows XP. I want to do that ProcessStartInfo class and  Process.Start() method.

In current user there is no password.

so how can i do that ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Process.Start` will execute under the current account by default. You do not have to provide credentials for that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use

```
Process.Start(your_exe);
```